# PdfMake keep few elements on the same page Angular

Tags: angular, pdf, pdfmake

I have few elements (not a table) that should be on the same page.
for example:

```
Name: XXX,
Age: XXX,
Description: XXX
```

How to make sure that if some of the elements does not have space on the page, to move all these elements together to the next page?
The height of the elements is  not fixed, and not all elements exist.